# Find if workbook was opened using VBA or by user

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a macro workbook Excel 2007 with a workbook open event.
Inside the workbook open event is it possible for me find if the workbook was opened by the user from windows or from another workbook using vba...

Comment: Ummm, I cannot think of a way. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when the workbook is opened by the user i need to run some macros to initialize menus like comboboxes etc , but i also need to open the workbook using vba to update links and other info, as this happens quiet often it slows down the execution as workbook open fires each time i open the workbook.

Comment: Why not show a non modal userform for 3 seconds asking if the user wants to run the macro? If the code opens the file the userform will not get an input and will autoclose in 3 secs

Comment: That's a thought ... i will try that

Comment: It works , but the whole idea is to quicken the process , the 3 second gap will still increase execution time and its to little for the the person to respond to.

Comment: Yup we could increase the wait time but then like you said it will increase the execution time. unfortunately I an sorry I do not know of any other way. If I can think of something then I will post back :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , i will update if i happen to come across another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it fits your needs, but you can open a workbook in your VBA code without firing the events:

```
'Disable Events.
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Open your book.
Workbooks.open(Filename)

'Enable Events.
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 0):

If this suits your purpose:

When opening with vba, change the name of the workbook before opening. Then change it back when done. Workbook_Open procedure just needs to check for the name of the workbook it is in.

To change the name of the workbook

you can open it, then use SaveAs method to close it again with the new name

use the Shell function

use a Microsoft Scripting Runtime object.